# How to Apply Masked SVG Patterns using Coord System of ObjectBoundingBox

Tags: html, svg, mask

I am writing inline SVG code for a data visualization and I'm trying to apply a `<mask>` which I filled with a `<pattern>` to multiple SVG `<rect>` elements.

I can't find a combination of `patternUnits`, `patternContentUnits`, `maskUnits` and `maskContentUnits` that makes the mask filling 100% of each rect it gets applied to without stretching the pattern. Is it even possible? The pattern itself is not that complicated and should look like this: [correct pattern dimensions applied](https://i.stack.imgur.com/96hQO.png)

Due to performance optimization I wan't the `<defs>` tag to live in a separate svg at root level of my component.

```css
#my-defs {
  position: absolute;
  top: -1000px;
  left: -1000px;
}

#my-svg {
  width: 200px;
  height: 3em;
}

#my-svg rect {
  width: 100%;
  height: 80%;
}
```

```html
<svg id="my-defs">
  <defs>
    <pattern id="diagonal-hatch-pattern" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="4" height="4">
      <path d="M-1,1 l2,-2 M0,4 l4,-4 M3,5 l2,-2" stroke="white" strokeWidth="1" />
    </pattern>
    <mask id="diagonal-hatch-mask" x="0" y="0" width="1" height="1" maskContentUnits="objectBoundingBox">
      <rect fill="url(#diagonal-hatch-pattern)" x="0" y="0" width="1" height="1" />
    </mask>
  </defs>
</svg>

<svg id="my-svg">
  <rect fill="steelblue" mask="url(#diagonal-hatch-mask)" />
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

I could get it to work by changing `maskContentUnits` back to its default value of `userSpaceOnUse` but that doesn't feel right because of the static dimensions i would have to assign to the mask shape. It would be much better if the `rect` in my mask would scale to each object the mask gets applied to.

So, if anyone has a better solution, I would be very thankful...

```css
#my-defs {
  position: absolute;
  top: -1000px;
  left: -1000px;
}

#my-svg {
  width: 200px;
  height: 3em;
}

#my-svg rect {
  width: 100%;
  height: 80%;
}
```

```html
<svg id="my-defs">
  <defs>
    <pattern id="diagonal-hatch-pattern" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="4" height="4">
      <path d="M-1,1 l2,-2 M0,4 l4,-4 M3,5 l2,-2" stroke="white" strokeWidth="1" />
    </pattern>
    <mask id="diagonal-hatch-mask" x="0" y="0" width="1" height="1" maskContentUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <rect fill="url(#diagonal-hatch-pattern)" x="0" y="0" width="9000" height="9000" />
    </mask>
  </defs>
</svg>

<svg id="my-svg">
  <rect fill="steelblue" mask="url(#diagonal-hatch-mask)" />
</svg>
```